Importrange 2 different url- how to remove the blank cells between the spreadsheets
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("179zBHujwfCU-RX5378E7u5lfiVc5sNlK95ikemijRkY","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!H253:X270"); IMPORTRANGE("1AVAPqGRvAffQ1ANAdjzU5cYMGLvXIqZqy8CgsAqxZLM","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!I74:Y100")},
"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17")

typically this results to 1st data sets followed by hundreds of blank cells and then by the 2nd spreadsheet data set, is there a way to remove the blank cells ? if yes, everytime each spreadsheet were updated will the master column adjust as well?
Additional, would just want to remove the blank cells between the two separate spreadsheets/url. The blanks within each column from the data set should remain next to each other
after inportrange the blank row between the two data should be deleted


everytime each spreadsheet were updated will the master column adjust as well?

yes. but not always instantly. it can take up to 30 minutes as per documentation.
...use where Col is not null for example:
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("179zBHujwfCU-RX5378E7u5lfiVc5sNlK95ikemijRkY","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!H253:X270"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1AVAPqGRvAffQ1ANAdjzU5cYMGLvXIqZqy8CgsAqxZLM","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!I74:Y100")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17 
  where Col1 is not null", )

change Col1 to column number that fits (eg. always not empty if data present)
and as @Harun24hr points out, if you call all columns from range you dont need select at all. just skip it like:
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("179zBHujwfCU-RX5378E7u5lfiVc5sNlK95ikemijRkY","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!H253:X270"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1AVAPqGRvAffQ1ANAdjzU5cYMGLvXIqZqy8CgsAqxZLM","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!I74:Y100")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", )

or you may try REDUCE:
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(MAP(x, y, 
 LAMBDA(e, f, QUERY("♣"&FLATTEN(QUERY("♥"&TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE(e, f)),,9^9)),,9^9))),,9^9), 
 "♣")), "♥"), "where Col1 <> ' '", 0))(
 {"179zBHujwfCU-RX5378E7u5lfiVc5sNlK95ikemijRkY";"1AVAPqGRvAffQ1ANAdjzU5cYMGLvXIqZqy8CgsAqxZLM"},
 {"'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!I74:Y100";"'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!H253:X270"}))



I was going to post same. =QUERY( {IMPORTRANGE("179zBHujwfCU-RX5378E7u5lfiVc5sNlK95ikemijRkY","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!H253:X270"); IMPORTRANGE("1AVAPqGRvAffQ1ANAdjzU5cYMGLvXIqZqy8CgsAqxZLM","'7 May 2024 - 20 May 2024'!I74:Y100")}, "select * where Col1 is not null")
